# Laravel PHP JSON Decoding

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a code which looks like this

```html
"""
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Content-Type:  application/json\r\n
Date:          Tue, 08 Nov 2002 05:46:42 GMT\r\n
\r\n
{\n
    "request": {\n
        "body": ""\n
    },\n
    "response": {\n
        "status": 1,\n
        "users": [\n
            {\n
                "user_id": 1,\n
                "username": "john.doe",\n
                "account_status": "1",\n
                "online_status": 1,\n
            }
        ]\n
    }\n
}
"""
```

That value came from a database, the only problem I've got is that, I can't decode it using json_decode... Are there any class or function that can decode this to convert into array()?

Comment: Post the code that returns this data

Comment: Where do you need them? At the frontend or backend?

Comment: Because thats not a valid JSON. If thats the only format you can get, you first have to clean it then decode it.

Comment: This is a whole HTTP Response, of course you can't convert that to JSON. You have to extract the body with the JSON part.

Comment: Yah, someone says that it is indeed the whole HTTP response, that data is from an sql query

select * from logs where log_id = 1

data type is longtext

That's what I need to know, how to clean it and extract the body to convert into json format

Comment: Why are you saving the whole HTTP response at the first place? Save only the body instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment, what you have there is a whole HTTP response. It holds the JSON data in the body, so you need to parse that. Here's one way to go about it:

```
preg_match("/\{(.*)\}/s", $rawResponse, $matches);
```

This matches everything between the firs "{" and the last "}", which is where the JSON data lives, and stores every match in `$matches`. Since there should only be one match, we're interested in `$matches[0]`.

Now you only need to decode it back:

```
$data = json_decode($matches[0]);

// or 
// $data = json_decode($matches[0], true) 
// if you want an associative array instead of an object.
```

**Caveat:** This won't work with your example, because it's not valid JSON. The comma after `"online_status": 1,` makes it invalid so `json_decode` will return `false`. But I guess you just stripped some lines in your question for better readability.

If you have control over how things are stored, you should definitely consider only storing the JSON data so you wouldn't have to deal with such issues. If you still somehow need the whole raw response, maybe store it in another table / column. This makes things **a lot** easier, especially with Laravel. For instance, if the data is something like a `details` field on a `Transaction` model or something, you could do someting like this:

```
class Transaction extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'json'
    ];

}
```

Now, when accessing `$transaction->details` you'll automatically get an array. And this even works in both directions: `$transaction->details = ['new' => 'data']` will convert it to JSON before saving it. So you wouldn't have to deal with converting back and forth at all.

Comment: Really, he should be getting the body without the headers in the first place, not trying to strip off the headers after the fact.

Comment: @Simba That's exactly what I'm saying in the second part of my answer. OP said the data comes from a DB, so it's already there in the given form. We don't know if he's in control of the incoming requests / responses or how the data is stored, but if he is, storing only the relevant body of course would make more sense than having to grapple with parsing it.

Comment: I don't have any control of the request, it's been there for a long time... I'm just extracting the data from their database.

Thank you for this answer btw. This basically answered my concern.